# ajax jquery submit with icontact form

Tags: jquery, ajax, icontact

I am trying to use Ajax with icontact.. my code makes the form submit however it shows an error message, despite the form working and the details dropping into the list.

```
$('.error').hide();
$('.erroremail').hide();
$('#successcontainer').hide();
function verifyRequired()
{ 
    var eReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; // regex to check valid email
    var email = $('input[name="fields_email"]').val();
    var name = $('input[name="fields_fname"]').val();
    var phone = $('input[name="fields_phone"]').val();
    var data = $("#form-popup").serialize()

    if (email == "") {
        $('input[name="fields_email"]').focus();
        $('.error').show();
        return false;
    } else if (!eReg.test(email)) {
        $('input[name="fields_email"]').focus();
        $('.erroremail').show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (name == "") {
        $('input[name="fields_name"]').focus();
        $('.error').show();
        return false;
    }
    else if (phone == "") {
        $('input[name="fields_phone"]').focus();
        $('.error').show();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: data,
            success: function(){
                alert('success')
            },
            error: function(){
                alert('failure')
            },
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

So the form is submitting the details fine, but showing the failure message?

So i'm almost there, anyone know why?

Cheers

here is the form also

```
<form id="form-popup" method="post" action="" name="icpsignup" accept-charset="UTF-8" onsubmit="return verifyRequired();" >
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/thanks.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="errorredirect" value="http://www.icontact.com/www/signup/error.html">
    <input type="text" name="fields_fname" class="input" id="name" placeholder="Full Name" />
    <input type="text" name="fields_email" class="input" id="email" placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="text" name="fields_phone" class="input" id="phone" placeholder="Telephone" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" />

    <input type="hidden" name="listid" value="xxxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="specialid:xxxxx" value="xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientid" value="xxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="formid" value="xxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="reallistid" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="doubleopt" value="0">
</form>
```

Comment: It would help us a lot if you shared the error message.

Comment: syntax error: `alert('failure') },` <- remove the comma

Comment: it just popups an alert saying failure for now.

Comment: syntax error II: `var eReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;` <- Example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/validate-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: thanks for this, is there anything obvious that might be showing the error message despite the ajax working and the details dropping into icontact crm?

Answer (score 0):

I have run your code in my local server and I have not found any syntax errors.

The problem I face with using your code is "**Cross-Origin Request Blocked**".

**Browsers do not allow AJAX requests to another domain**, if you try to use the form on the site app.icontact.com (or maybe icontact.com) it will work.

If you cannot use icontact.com for the form then I suggest you write a PHP code (which is the server side language in our case) to process `jsonp`. This is a workaround for cross-origin policy.

Add dataType: `jsonp` to `$.ajax`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://app.icontact.com/icp/signup.php", 
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: data,
    success: function(){
        alert('success')
    },
    error: function(){
        alert('failure')
    },
})
```

Executing the above code gave me a syntax error from signup.php, so I am assuming processing the jsonp correctly will get you the success alert.